# what are the names of these controls in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, controls

If you look at most Google Play Apps like

### Google Play Magazine

:
[image]

### Google Play Music

[image]

How do you call it? On a scale from 1 to 10 based on beginner programming level skill, how do you rate the difficulty of implementing them? Where are the best places to start?

Comment: anyway I tried Master/Detail Flow, I guess it's not it. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

There is [an example](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) from the official documentation on how to implement them. In my experience, I would say it's easy to implement to a simple one. But as such in above picture, it's a little more tricker but I've seen [some examples](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/).